# Express JS customize high water mark

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest

I have a Node JS application performing posting of data from client to server . The client makes use of ReadableStream to prepare data in chunks and the ReadableStream is piped to http.request object (which is a writable stream) . To improve performance we provided a high water mark in the ReadableStream constructor . But in the server side we are using express JS to consume the data . However it still is not reading the chunks by the size specified by highWaterMark but in 16 KB chunks . Is there a way to customize the high water mark in Express JS

Comment: The 16KB HWM is a NodeJS default. Not sure how to change that in ExpressJS tho.

Comment: You might be able to add an event handler for the [`connection` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection) of the underlying HTTP server, and set the high water mark on the socket (although I'm not sure if you can actually set that on sockets).